# Ошибка в python. Пишет ошибка в 6 строке

Tags: python

```
n = input()
ans = 0
digits = '0123456789'
for i in range(len(n)):
 for digit in digits:
 new = int(n[:i] + digit + n[i + 1:])
 if digit != n[i] and new % 3 == 0:
 ans = max(ans, new)
print(ans)
```

Comment: Ну да, после начала цикла в 5 строке должен обязательно начинаться новый блок кода с отступом, а вы его не начали

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Отступы забыл)
После цикла/условий/функций ставится табуляция

Answer (score -1):

Спасибо всем огромное! Все решено !

```
n = input()
ans = 0
digits = '0123456789'
for i in range(len(n)):
    for digit in digits:
        new = int(n[:i] + digit + n[i + 1:])
        if digit != n[i] and new % 3 == 0:
            ans = max(ans, new)
print(ans)
```